# excel sheet style changed after mergin it into one new excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I have written the following code which reads excel files from excelFilesPath, **put the files with the same prefix in one excel file** and rename the Excel file to have the prefix only.
Example: The code **merges** the files **a.b.1.xlsx** and **a.b.2.xlsx** to one **single excel** file with the new name **a.b.xlsx**

```
private void mergeExcelFiles(String excelFilesPath) {
    Map<String, List<List<String>>> moduleReportFiles = fileNames.entrySet().stream().collect(groupingBy(
            e -> e.getKey().substring(0, e.getKey().lastIndexOf(".")), mapping(e -> e.getValue(), toList())));

    Workbook workbookTo;
    Workbook workbookFrom;

    for (Entry<String, List<List<String>>> moduleNameReportsList : moduleReportFiles.entrySet()) {
        List<String> files = moduleReportFiles.get(moduleNameReportsList.getKey()).stream().flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        files = files.stream().sorted().collect(toList());
        File f;
        if (files.size() < 1) {// consider only modules that have at least 2 reports
            continue;
        } else if (files.size() == 1) { // if a module has only one report then rename it to the module name
            f = new File(files.get(0));
            f.renameTo(new File(excelFilesPath + "/" + moduleNameReportsList.getKey() + ".xlsx"));
        } else {
            try {
                workbookTo = new XSSFWorkbook(new File(files.get(0)));

                // workbookTo.setSheetOrder(files.get(0), 0);
                f = new File(files.get(0));
                f.delete();
                files.remove(0);
                for (String file : files) {
                    workbookFrom = new XSSFWorkbook(new File(file)); // workbook that needs to be merged
                    for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < workbookFrom.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetIndex++) {
                        XSSFSheet sheetTo = (XSSFSheet) workbookTo
                                .createSheet(workbookFrom.getSheetAt(sheetIndex).getSheetName());
                        XSSFSheet sheetFrom = (XSSFSheet) workbookFrom.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
                        XSSFRangeCopier xssfRangeCopier = new XSSFRangeCopier(sheetFrom, sheetTo);
                        int lastRow = sheetFrom.getLastRowNum();
                        int lastCol = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
                            Row row = sheetFrom.getRow(i);
                            if (row != null) {
                                if (row.getLastCellNum() > lastCol) {
                                    lastCol = row.getLastCellNum();
                                }
                                sheetTo.setDefaultRowHeight(sheetFrom.getDefaultRowHeight());
                            }
                        }

                        for (int j = 0; j < lastCol; j++) {
                            sheetTo.setColumnWidth(j, sheetFrom.getColumnWidth(j));
                        }

                        CellRangeAddress cellAddresses = new CellRangeAddress(0, lastRow, 0, lastCol);
                        xssfRangeCopier.copyRange(cellAddresses, cellAddresses, true, true);
                        workbookTo.write(new FileOutputStream(
                                new File(excelFilesPath + "/" + moduleNameReportsList.getKey() + ".xlsx")));
                    }
                    f = new File(file);
                    if(f.delete())// delete older file
                    {
                        log.info("report file deleted successfully");
                    }
                }

            } catch (InvalidFormatException e1) {
                log.error(e1.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                log.error(e1.getMessage());
            } // the workbook that we merge all excel files into it
        }
    }
}
```

The code does that perfect. The Problem that I am facing now is that **only one excel sheet** has the **original style**. **all other sheets** **shows borders** some how which is wrong (find attached screenshot). **How can I get the origin layout of all sheets?**

[image]

Comment: Please make this a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What kind of object is `fileNames`? What does it contain?

Comment: And what method is `toList`? Not `Collectors.toList()`, that is clear, but method `toList()` called in `...moduleReportFiles = ...` and `files = ...`.

Comment: fileNames contains the names of excel files with the path, mapped to prefix name. example: {"a.b", "C:/folder/a.b.1.xlsx"} but this is not the place that changed the style

Comment: "but this is not the place that changed the style": No, but we always need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make the problem reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your picture the source sheets seems have set display gridlines to false. This is stored in sheet view settings of CTWorksheet for `XSSFSheet`. So if the copied sheet also shall have set that so, then the sheet view settings of CTWorksheet also needs to be copied. To do so do:

```
...
sheetTo.getCTWorksheet().setSheetViews(sheetFrom.getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews());
...
```

But `sheetViews` also stores the setting about selected sheets, so set selected of `sheetTo` false, else multiple sheets will be selected in the result workbook

```
...
sheetTo.setSelected(false); 
...
```

But additional you might get problems with the code lne:

```
...
XSSFSheet sheetTo = (XSSFSheet) workbookTo..createSheet(workbookFrom.getSheetAt(sheetIndex).getSheetName());
...
```

What if multiple `workbookFrom` workbooks have sheets with the same sheet name? Then this line will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` because the `workbookTo` workbook already contains a sheet with this name. So the need is to consider that sheets from multiple workbookFrom could have the same name. If so, then append (n), where n is a counter number,  to the name to make it unique in the result workbook.

Complete example as [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class ExcelMergeFiles {
    
    private void mergeExcelFiles(String excelFilesPath, List<String> files) {
        File f1 = new File(files.get(0));
        try (
                Workbook workbookTo = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(f1)); // workbook that will be the result
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(excelFilesPath + "/" + "result" + ".xlsx"));
            ) {
            files.remove(0); // first file is workbookTo and not needs to be merged into the result
            for (String file : files) {
                File f = new File(file);
                try (
                        Workbook workbookFrom = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(f)); // workbook that needs to be merged into the result
                    ) {
                    for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < workbookFrom.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetIndex++) {
                        // get sheetFrom
                        XSSFSheet sheetFrom = (XSSFSheet) workbookFrom.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
                        
                        //consider that sheets from multiple workbookFrom could have the same name, if so, then append (n)
                        int n = 1;
                        String sheetName = sheetFrom.getSheetName();
                        while (workbookTo.getSheet(sheetName) != null) {
                            if (sheetName.matches("^.*? \\(\\d*\\)$")) {
                                sheetName = sheetName.replaceAll(" \\(\\d*\\)", " ("+ ++n +")");
                            } else {
                                sheetName = sheetName + " ("+ ++n +")";
                            }
                        }
                        
                        // create sheetTo
                        XSSFSheet sheetTo = (XSSFSheet) workbookTo.createSheet(sheetName);
                        
                        //get last used column of sheetFrom
                        int lastRow = sheetFrom.getLastRowNum();
                        int lastCol = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
                            Row row = sheetFrom.getRow(i);
                            if (row != null) {
                                if (row.getLastCellNum() > lastCol) {
                                    lastCol = row.getLastCellNum();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                         // copy used range from sheetFrom to sheetTo
                        if (lastRow >= 0 && lastCol >= 0) { // only if there is content in the sheet
                            CellRangeAddress cellAddresses = new CellRangeAddress(0, lastRow, 0, lastCol);
                            XSSFRangeCopier xssfRangeCopier = new XSSFRangeCopier(sheetFrom, sheetTo);
                            xssfRangeCopier.copyRange(cellAddresses, cellAddresses, true, true);
                        }
                        
                        // copy the column widths from sheetFrom to sheetTo
                        for (int j = 0; j < lastCol; j++) {
                            sheetTo.setColumnWidth(j, sheetFrom.getColumnWidth(j));
                        }
                        
                        // copy default row height from sheetFrom to sheetTo
                        sheetTo.setDefaultRowHeight(sheetFrom.getDefaultRowHeight());
                        
                        // copy row heights from sheetFrom to sheetTo
                        for (int i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
                            Row rowFrom = sheetFrom.getRow(i);
                            Row rowTo = sheetTo.getRow(i);
                            if (rowFrom != null && rowTo != null) {
                                rowTo.setHeight(rowFrom.getHeight());
                            }
                        }

                        // copy the sheetViews which stores the setting about visibility of grid lines for example
                        sheetTo.getCTWorksheet().setSheetViews(sheetFrom.getCTWorksheet().getSheetViews());
                        // sheetViews also stores the setting about selected sheets, so set selected of sheetTo false, else multiple sheets will be selected in result workbook
                        sheetTo.setSelected(false);
                        
                        // workbookFrom is closeables which closes because of try with resources
                    }   
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                f.delete();                
            }
            // write the workbookTo as the result.xlsx
            workbookTo.write(out);
            // workbookTo and out are closeables which closes because of try with resources
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        f1.delete();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
        files.add("./ExcelFiles/a.xlsx");
        files.add("./ExcelFiles/b.xlsx");
        files.add("./ExcelFiles/c.xlsx");
        ExcelMergeFiles app = new ExcelMergeFiles();
        app.mergeExcelFiles("./ExcelFiles", files);
    }
}
```

Expects files `a.xlsx`,  `b.xlsx`,  `c.xlsx` in directory `./ExcelFiles` and merges sheets form  `b.xlsx` and `c.xlsx` into `a.xlsx` and stores the result as `result.xlsx`.

Comment: Can you please edit the code so that you remove the older files and close workbookTo? I as because when I do this, the older files get written again after I use workbookTo.close();. really strange

Comment: @user1167753: Done. The `workbookTo.write` was on the wrong place. This should only be done once when all work is done and not multiple times after merging each sheet.

Comment: can you adapt it please with  try-with-resources Statement? i never get it working with it